# Stream response in a file

Tags: file, asp-classic, response

I want to stream the response of the actual page in a file.

This is what I do for creating the file :

```
set fso=server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fic= session("DIRECTORY_BASE") & "/data/download/temp.xls"
If fso.FileExists(fic) Then fso.deletefile(fic)
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fic, 2, True) 
pageContent = ?
objFile.Write pageContent
```

How can i get the content of the current page and have my pagecontent variable ?

Comment: Call the ASP page via XHR then save the response text from the XHR to the file.

Comment: Are you talking about streaming the text file like seen here -- >
https://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_ref_textstream.asp

Comment: @easleyfixed No they want to request a page and have the response from the page saved to a file.